# How to sum a range that includes #N/A, BUT if the range contains ALL #N/A's return #N/A?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically if I have a range:

````
```A1 = #N/A
A2 = 0
A3 = 0```
````

I want to return A4 = 0
But if range:

````
```A1 = #N/A
A2 = #N/A
A3 = #N/A```
````

I want A4 = #N/A.

Is it possible to achieve this while containing all the processing in one cell? If possible I do not want to pass values to multiple cells.

I've tried 
    `=SUMIF(A1:A3,"<>#N/A",A1:A3)`
but if the entire range is #N/A this formula returns 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but you could add a COUNTIF

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A3,"#N/A")=3,"#N/A",SUMIF(A1:A3,"<>#N/A"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great. I did one make one change though: `=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A3,"#N/A")=3,**NA()**,SUMIF(A1:A3,"<>#N/A"))` . This allows it to return a true error instead of just a string, avoids some problems down the line.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
=IF(COUNT(A1:A3),SUMIF(A1:A3,"<>#N/A"),NA())
```